# Directly update button state JavaFX

Tags: eclipse, button, javafx

I have a GUI that uploads a bunch of settings via serial once the 'upload' button is pressed.

This upload takes some time and has some Thread.sleep's in it, so during upload the GUI freezes but still allows the user to press the upload button some more, which results in even more freezing.

What would be the best way to directly disable the upload button, upload in the background, and enable the button when finished?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply.

To answer my own question, I already found a simple solution by creating a task:

```
public class uploadTask extends Task<String> {
  @Override
  protected String call() throws Exception {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [RxJavaFx](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaFX).

```java
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import io.reactivex.Observable;
    import io.reactivex.rxjavafx.observables.JavaFxObservable;
    import io.reactivex.rxjavafx.schedulers.JavaFxScheduler;
    import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class BackgroundTaskButtonApp extends Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
            Button button = new Button("Run!");
            StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(button);

            Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 400, 400);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

            JavaFxObservable.actionEventsOf(button)
            .doOnNext(event -> button.setDisable(true))
            .switchMap(event -> Observable.just(event).observeOn(Schedulers.single()).doOnNext(e -> runLongTask()))
            .observeOn(JavaFxScheduler.platform())
            .doOnNext(event -> button.setDisable(false))
            .subscribe();
        }

        private void runLongTask() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " runLongTask()");
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```